# Where Can I Find Stock Photos Large Enough for a Billboard?

Tags: stock-images, billboard

Wondering if anyone here has ever designed a billboard incorporating stock photography. I've been searching and searching, but I can't find anything at the dimensions I'm look for!

Comment: Hi Erin, welcome to the site! I've never designed a billboard, but I think the answers to the following questions will help answer your question: _What is the dimension of the billboard? What DPI are you designing for? What dimensions are you looking for?_ Please [edit] your question to include that information

Comment: There's nothing special about bill board stock photos. They're just printed much larger.

Comment: But because they are printed so much larger they will be a much lower resolution by that stage.  A 300 dpi image could easily become a 10dpi image on a billboard.

Answer (score 2):

I've designed billboards for a few different vendors. Most of them have requested 1 tenth scale (something like 14" x 48") at 300ppi. The amount of pocket/bleed room will differ per vendor. Each vendor may have quite different requirements, but in my experience, stock art listed as high or very high resolution will most likely be just fine. Keep in mind that most viewers are going to be tens of yards away, making the medium much more forgiving that a poster or something you hold in your hand to view. An important distinction will be to ask if the billboard is traditional or video. More and more suppliers are switching to LED video boards, which have their own set of requirements (RGB vs CMYK, etc.)  Congrats on getting a billboard client, and good luck!

Comment: Out of explicit requirements, OP must either create an exclusively large image or create it by virtue of vectorization. Also, modern programs for work with raster iamges such as GIMP provide a wide range of templates.

Comment: I've struggled to find images that even fit these proportions.  Even a 5000 pixel image at 300dpi goes down to about 10dpi once stretched to fit a 3 metre wide board.

Comment: Eoin, 5000/118.11(3 meters converted to inches) = 42.3333.
At 3 meters, a 5000 pixel wide image would print at 42.33 ppi. That's not stellar, but it's fine for a billboard. Also, Photoshop now has remarkable upsampling capabilities if you wish to increase that. I don't think it would be necessary though.